# Should an if condition check be repeatedly done inside a for loop for the sake of readability and brevity or just once outside it?

Tags: java

Here is the code in question, I can either check for the condition once outside:

```
if (booleanCondition) {
  for (Integer x : integerList) {
    doSomething(x);
    doSomethingElse(x);
  }
} else {
  for (Integer x : integerList) {
    doSomething(x);
  }
}
```

Or inside:

```
for (Integer x : integerList) {
  doSomething(x);
  if (booleanCondition) {
    doSomethingElse(x);
  }
}
```

The first code sample is (imo) less readable and longer. The second one is concise and easy to understand, yet inefficiently checks repeatedly for the condition.

I'm not sure if the compiler is smart enough to be able to reduce the second example to the first (*I'm using java 8, javac 1.8.0_45*), what do you think would be the correct way to write this then?

Comment: There's the third option: `boolean condition = checkCondition(); ... if(condition)...`

Comment: What is `booleanCondition` actually doing? Is this constant?

Comment: @Tunaki it's passed in as a parameter, this is in an Action.

Comment: That tells nothing about it. First, did you measure any kind of performance difference between the two? It's pretty hard to reason on things when we have no info as to what it is we're really talking about. What are the size of the lists? Is the boolean a constant? What is `doSomething` actually doing? This is all pretty vague.

Comment: To answer part of your question, it does not compile to the same Java byte code.

Answer (score 0):

If the boolean condition does not depend of the elements inside the list, then the check statement should be outside the loop.

Comment: Care to explain why? First code has duplicated logic.

Comment: It may, but imagine if you take the second code and the boolean condition =/= f(element of the list), then weither the statement of the condition is true or false, you are repeating the check process N times where N is the number of the elements in the list.

Comment: The impact might be heavy if you call for a helper class that requires some database connection or something like that, where you could have done it once.

Comment: Call that helper class once, store the result. But what I was trying to say is that you should expand on your answer with an [edit]. Because for now, it's a single unbacked statement.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new, this was one of my first posts on stackoverflow.
I haven't thought of the possibility to store, since my thinking was focusing on the condition itself. 

As you said, the condition is relatively a constant. I don't have an idea then wither java compiler can do some optimization or no, but  as you said, logically, you either need to check it once, and you get less readability, or check for multiple times and do the checks for each one.

Sorry if I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Java 8 you can write something like :

```
Consumer<Integer> consumer;
if (booleanCondition) consumer = (x) -> doSomething(x);
else consumer = (x) -> { doSomething(x); doSomethingElse(x) };

integerList.stream().forEach(consumer);
```

It's both concise and does not repeat logic.